# Error while installing R on windows 8

Tags: r, windows-8

I am trying to install 'R' on Windows 8. But when I start the installer, it gives error like: shellexecuteex failed code 1053 and some text.

While running the setup:

[image]

While running it as administrator:

[image]

Comment: You may try right clicking on one of the program setup file and select run as administrator to install the program or http://www.forumswindows8.com/installation-setup/install-problem-error-shellexecuteex-failed-5713.htm

Comment: I tried. But shows error: The service didn't respond to start or control statement in a timely fashion. Same error shows when I try to run "msconfig" from the run window.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

Comment: Please add full error message, and more info about your OS.

Comment: I have edited the post with the pics of the errors. Please have a look.

Comment: The fact that msconfig doesn't work means that you have very serious configuration issues. As noted in the link by @Aashu, make sure you have the latest updates installed. This question might be better asked on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the application is already in the application list if so, delete it.
Sign out from all the account and try installing with Admin account.